# Redirect with 301 status in Spring MVC 4 without ModelAndView

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I try to have a redirect with `301 Status Code` (you know I want to be SEO friendly etc).

I do use `InternalResourceViewResolver` so I wanted to use some kind of a code similar to `return "redirect:http://google.com"` in my Controller. 
This though would send a `302 Status Code`

What I have tried is using a `HttpServletResponse` to set header

```
@RequestMapping(value="/url/{seo}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String detail(@PathVariable String seo, HttpServletResponse response){
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    return "redirect:http://google.com";
}
```

It does still return `302`.

After checking documentation and Google results I've come up with the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/url/{seo}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView detail(@PathVariable String seo){
    RedirectView rv = new RedirectView();
    rv.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
    rv.setUrl("http://google.com");
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(rv);
    return mv;
}
```

It does work perfectly fine and as expected, returning code `301`

I would like to achieve it without using ModelAndView (Maybe it's perfectly fine though). Is it possible?

NOTE: included snippets are just parts of the detail controller and redirect does happen only in some cases (supporting legacy urls).

Comment: You can return the `RedirectView` directly.

Comment: It would still require me to change the method return type, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest using redirectView of spring like you have it. You have to have a complete URL including the domain etc for that to work, else it will do a 302. Or if you have access to HttpServletResponse, then you can do the below as below.

```
public void send301Redirect(HttpServletResponse response, String newUrl) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
        response.setHeader("Location", newUrl);
        response.setHeader("Connection", "close");
    }
```

Comment: No reason for `Connection: close` if your redirect is on the same domain.

Comment: You may also need `response.flushBuffer();`

Comment: @AlexR thank you, this line should be included in the answer

Answer (score 9):

Not sure when it was added, but at least on v4.3.7 this works. You set an attribute on the REQUEST and the spring View code picks it up:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/url/{seo}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String detail(@PathVariable String seo, HttpServletRequest request){
    request.setAttribute(View.RESPONSE_STATUS_ATTRIBUTE, HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
    return "redirect:http://google.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already return a ModelAndView and don't want to use HttpServletResponse, you can use this snippet:

```
        RedirectView rv = new RedirectView("redirect:" + myNewURI);
        rv.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
        return new ModelAndView(rv);
```

Comment: The whole point of the question is that he _doesn't_ "already return a ModelAndView" and doesn't want to, so this doesn't answer the question.