# Loading external dynamic Script in html (header) with spring REST-service

Tags: java, spring, rest, head, external-js

**I want to load an *dynamic* external JavaScript path in a head of a html-site**.

But I don't know how to implement it. Is REST-service a good idea?
In my project I'am already using REST-service with spring.

Other ideas?

Thank you in advance!

**HTML**

```
<head>...
    <script src="/site/ext-js"></script>
</head>
```

**Rest (Java)**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ext-js", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getExternalJS() {...}
```

Comment: One possible solution would be for example the following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28726274

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be for example the following (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28726274)

**HTML**

```
<head>...
    <script src="/site/ext-js"></script>
</head>
```

**Rest (Java)**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ext-js", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getExternalJS(HttpServletResponse response, String newUrl) {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
    response.setHeader("Location", newUrl);
    response.setHeader("Connection", "close");
}
```